# How to split words that are connected with ellipses using Java API

Tags: java, regex, split

Trying to normalize a String and store the words in a String Array, but the words that are connected with ellipses (eg `Lorem...ipsum`) are not split correctly; the resulting array is `[loremipsum, dolor, sit, amet]`.

```
String teststr = "Lorem...ipsum dolor sit amet.";
String nstr = Normalizer.normalize(teststr, Normalizer.Form.NFD)
    .toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-zα-ωA-ZΑ-Ω0-9 ]", "");
String[] words = nstr.split("\\s+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));
```

Comment: Change `""` to `" "` for your replacement string.

Comment: @4castle it worked! been trying for a couple of hours to make it work, not very familiar with regex, thank you for your answer.

Comment: A bit simpler to drop the `replaceAll()` and do `nstr.split("[^a-zα-ω0-9]+")` (also you don’t need the uppercase letters in the regex when you have converted to lowercase).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for more than just this:

```
String[] parts = str.split("(?iu)[^a-zα-ω0-9]+");
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/tpc7qO).

Note the use of the `i` flag (ignore case) and `u` flag (Unicode, which correctly handles capitalisation of Greek letters), so you don't even need the `Normalizer`.